# assign an array to a variable then switch in a series of condition statements

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, arrays, variables

I am new to programming and very new to objective c so I apologize for any incorrect terminology, or possibly making an easy concept more difficult than it is.

I have two very simple integer arrays that I want to switch based on the current device

```
 int iPhoneDevice[2] = {320,410};
 int iPadDevice[2] = {768,1024};
```

How would I assign each array to a single variable based on the current device??? Along the same idea as this.

```
if([[CurrentDevice] isEqualToString:@"iphone"]) {
        foo = iPhoneDevice[];      
    }else{
        foo = iPadDevice[];
    }
```

I need to be able to call both values of "foo" in my next conditional statement based on portrait. In my mind the logic would be similar to this.

```
 if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        bar = foo[1];
    }else {
        bar = foo[0];
    }
```

I have the intended result with an extra nested if, but I am trying to condense/clean up my code as much as possible. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int iPhoneDevice[2] = {320,410};
int iPadDevice[2] = {768,1024};

// I think this is the c syntax you're looking for
int *foo;

// CodaFi always has awesome amounts of knowledge handy
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
   foo = iPadDevice;
} else {
   foo = iPhoneDevice;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd approach it this way:

```
CGSize iPhoneDeviceSize = CGSizeMake (320, 410);
CGSize iPadDeviceSize   = CGSizeMake (768, 1024);
CGSize foo;

int bar;

// assign to foo the appropriate device size based on the user interface idiom
foo = ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ?
      iPadDeviceSize : iPhoneDeviceSize;

// assign to bar the width of the screen based on the orientation of the device.
bar = ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
       [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) ?
      size.width : size.height;
```

Not sure that's entirely what you were after, but it's what I'd do, based on the code you're presenting.

Comment: Excellent ternary statements. +1 for efficiency and the use of CGSize.

Comment: I will try this now, thanks for the help! My only concern is I don't need the full dimensions, I am using the screen dimensions separately as a reference to the x and y axis to place an ad.

Comment: Ah; I assumed screen dimensions since the numbers were so close to the actual dimensions (esp. the iPad). Hope it helps, though!

Answer (score 1):

To get whether the device is a mobile or an iPad (coincidentally, just called phone and pad), use `UIUserInterfaceIdiom`(`Pad`/`Phone`) like so:

```
if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    //device is an iPad
   bar = foo[1];
else
    //Device is an iPhone/iPod Touch
    bar = foo[0];
```

Or however you wish to style it.

Comment: I am getting the device ok and have tested it, my main question is regarding storing the arrays in a variable. Thank you for the help.

Comment: CGSize seems like the perfect vessel for your values.  It is meant for a height and a width value (and your example numbers are suspiciously close to the size of the various screens for eah device).

Comment: Yes :) .. Can I change CGSize dynamically with the orientation?

Comment: Actually, if you are trying to adjust the size of a UIView (or similar objects), setting it's autoResizingMask is a lot easier than hard coded values.

Comment: I am using these sizes as a base reference to the x and y axis so i can place ads in a CGRectMake with parameters similar to this (x,foo[1]-adHeight,adWidth,adHeight)

Comment: Ah!  Then use a CGSize then.  You can access its innards with `myCGSize.x` and `myCGSize.y`

Comment: Awesome! I will give it a try

Comment: Remember to upvote (every answer here is worthy), and mark your favorite as the answer.  Happy coding!